# In Silverlight, how to launch / navigate to another page?

Tags: silverlight

In Silverlight how can I launch / navigate to another page?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
System.Windows.Browser.HtmlPage.Window.Navigate(
   new Uri( "http://www.google.com" ),
   "_blank"
   );
```

You can leave out the target ("_blank") if you just want to navigate within your current browser window.

Answer (score 2):

To navigate to another page in from another page.

```
Frame frame =this.parent as Frame;
frame.navigate(new Uri("/Views/Details.xaml"),Uri.Relative);
```

Note, you must have a frame already in the MainPage.xaml.
So other pages are just calling the frame in the parent

Answer (score 1):

Assume You are editing code behind file of Page class

```
this.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/OtherPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
```

Comment: I think the OP meant a webpage, not a XAML page.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid issues with popups being blocked when you use _blank, ensure you call Navigate from the click event of a HyperlinkButton control, as described here:

http://www.tjsblog.net/2010/10/20/opening-a-new-chrome-page-in-silverlight/

Answer (score 0):

You all can also try this

```
this.content=new (place the page name which You want to navigate);

           but this code only works while navigate page having in same folder else You have to write like in given below manner
```

this.Content = new Views.(place the page name which You want to navigate);

```
         here in place of Views write the folder name where the page having...
```

Hope it's also helpful for you all.